# How to get JQuery get called inside another JS file in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC environment, and I'm currently having trouble on how can I make *JQuery* work,
on my `_Layout.cshtml` *(master page)*
I'm embedding all my scripts and stylesheets that I'll be using for most of the razor views, because that's how should it be , right?

So it's like this :

```
 <!-- This from the layout page-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" asp-append-version="true"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" asp-append-version="true">

 <partial name="../PartialViews/Header.cshtml" />

<!-- Rendering of body -->   @RenderBody()

 <partial name="../PartialViews/Footer.cshtml" />

<!-- This is where I put my js files -->
  <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" defer asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js" defer asp-append-version="true"></script>
<!-- Then my sections -->
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false) 
    @await RenderSectionAsync("CustomFunction", required: false) --this can't call jquery
    @await RenderSectionAsync("ServerTimeClock", required: false) -- this can call jquery
```

*Please note that my partial views Header and Footer doesn't contain any scripts just pure html elements*

This where I declare that section and this is my view:

```
...some html elements 


@section CustomFunction{
   
    <script src="~/js/DTR/DTR.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
@section ServerTimeClock {
  
    <script src="~/js/DTR/servertimeclock.js" defer asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <link href="~/css/DigitalClock.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />


}
```

and this the actual code inside `DTR.js` just for testing if jquery is working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("jQuery is working!");
});
```

then I have this error on browser's console

```
DTR.js?v=7VFYyQ2dDCwHwm5Q3uW7TWrMFYZ1DYIICSpaLSk6RTg:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Comment: jQuery has to be imported via a `<script>` tag **before** any script that uses it.

Comment: it's the same even if I put jquery on top of the file together with bootstrap css

Comment: Don't `defer` your jQuery import then.

Comment: you can try to import javascript libraries in `_ViewImports.cshtml` instead of `_Layout.cshtml`